# Update Duplicate Data in mysql table

Tags: mysql, duplicates, updates

I have a table in mysql where i have more than 1000 thousands of data.There are some records having duplicate data.I want to update the previous duplicate value only.Here is my table schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `property` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ref` longtext NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=545 ;


INSERT INTO property (ref) VALUES ('RH-R-1001');
INSERT INTO property (ref) VALUES ('RH-R-1002');
INSERT INTO property (ref) VALUES ('RH-R-1003');
INSERT INTO property (ref) VALUES ('RH-R-1004');
INSERT INTO property (ref) VALUES ('RH-R-1005');
INSERT INTO property (ref) VALUES ('RH-R-1003');
INSERT INTO property (ref) VALUES ('RH-R-1004');
INSERT INTO property (ref) VALUES ('RH-R-1005');
```

Here is fiddle  [MYSQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b434ec/1)

I want to update duplicate ref with new unique ref like RH-R-9999,RH-R-9998 etc  where id is smaller than other,For example First RH-H-1003 will be updated.
How this can be done?

Comment: "1000 thousand" sooo... millions?

Comment: This ment that too much records..nothing with question

Comment: I know, I was just joking :) On a more serious note. This will probably not be possible with a single query. Look into [Stored routines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html) with [cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html).

Comment: If we can only update with any number like 9999 etc?